# Input type date ng-model does not allow date data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From the server response, i want to map the date to my scope variable which type is 'date' in angular, as i do the same, am not able to map it as am getting the following error

```
angular.js:12798 Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2016-09-22T18:30:00.000Z` to be a date
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.12/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2016-09-22T18%3A30%3A00.0
```

Note: am mapping through $operatingDetails.date as exceptions array already in the `ng-repeat` loop

Any help please would be appreciated...

Html

```
 <div ng-repeat="operatingDetails in operatingDetails.exceptions" style="margin-top: 8px;">
             <div class="DateField">
             <input id="date2" type="date" ng-model="operatingDetails.date" style="" ng-change="customOPHchangeExpDateValid(operatingDetails.date, $parent.$parent.$index)"/>
             </div>
</div>
```

Js(Angular)

```
$scope.opertingHours.date
```

Server response

```
{
                "name" : "Custom Operation Hours1",
                "exceptions" : [{
                        "date" : "2016-09-15T18:30:00.000Z",
                        "starttime" : "10:02AM",
                        "endtime" : "10:02PM",
                        "_id" : "57de44c54feb409c2e13ff40",
                        "$$hashKey" : "object:207"
                    }
                ],
                "businesshour" : {
                    "sat" : {
                        "starttime" : "8:00AM",
                        "endtime" : "5:00PM"
                    },
                    "fri" : {
```

Comment: possible fiddle ? or a plunkar?

Comment: am so sorry, it is huge code, so i could do fiddle, sorry

Comment: are you using any ng-repeat?? if so update the ng-repeat with the post

Comment: yes,i added now you can check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are getting this error, as "date" ("date" : "2016-09-15T18:30:00.000Z",) is a string.So convert it to date from string.

So try this,

```
$scope.opertingHours.date = new Date(exceptions[0].date); //Converting string to date
```

Hope,it wll work for u.

Comment: how do you think this will work? Could u please refer my question once more?

Comment: Could you please look into this plunker,might help you.https://plnkr.co/edit/NGvrSOjjyaKgKOafyqfI?p=preview

Comment: Thank for this, but, am sorry, it is NOT working at my actual code.

Comment: Have a look at this plunker,might help u. https://plnkr.co/edit/NGvrSOjjyaKgKOafyqfI?p=preview

Comment: yes, it is works.. thanks.., I made your post as answer as the above link made the job...

Answer (score 0):

your **operatingDetails** is getting confused as you are using it in the **$scope** and in **ng-repeat** so try using another one as below

```
<div ng-repeat="oD in operatingDetails.exceptions" style="margin-top: 8px;">
                 <div class="DateField">
                 <input id="date2" type="date" ng-model="convertDate(oD.date)" style="" ng-change="customOPHchangeExpDateValid(oD.date, $parent.$parent.$index)"/>
                 </div>
</div>
```

Also add the following function to your controller

```
$scope.convertDate=function(inputDate){
return new Date(inputDate);
}
```

Comment: Where is it going to infinite loop?